# ¿Cómo reautentico con Firebase Auth?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase

En mi aplicación gestiono los usuarios desde el módulo de Autenticación de Firebase. No almaceno contraseñas en ninguna base de datos, y con ello me he topado con un problema:

Quiero hacer una pantalla en la que el usuario tenga que escribir su contraseña y si coincide con la que tiene vinculada, se borre la cuenta. Para ello se me ha ocurrido reautenticar al usuario con el valor del input que tiene que rellenar para confirmar y borrar.

El código es el siguiente:

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
    if (!password.getText().toString().isEmpty()) { //Si la contraseña no está vacía
        AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(user.getEmail(), password.getText().toString()); //Guardamos como creedenciales el email guardado y la contraseña que ha introducido
        user.reauthenticate(credential).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "NO OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Password es el nombre del EditText. Este fragment tiene un atributo previamente creado y relleno.

```
private FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser(); //Cargamos los datos del usuario
```

Mi problema está en que si introduces mal la contraseña se ejecutan los dos métodos igualmente, onSuccess y onFailure, por lo que no puedo llevar a cabo lo que quiero hacer. He probado OnComplete en vez de OnSuccess y pasa lo mismo. ¿Alguien sabe qué puede ser?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

El código funciona correctamente. Por alguna razón, me estaba dando ese fallo pero ya no lo da. Esta es la forma correcta de hacerlo.